# OpenLayers Popup not showing

Tags: openlayers, popup, map-function

I am creating a WebMap using GeoServer and OpenLayers. I am trying to create a popup to show information on a specific type of point feature.

The single-click event and function work well to get the name and coordinates of the points. However, the popup does not show up as expected and I could not find any problem in the code.

Any idea where I am making the mistake?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Web_GIS</title>
    
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="libs/bootstrap-5.1.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="libs/bootstrap-5.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


    <script src="libs/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="libs/v6.13.0-dist/ol.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/v6.13.0-dist/ol.css">


    <script src="libs/ol-layerswitcher-master/dist/ol-layerswitcher.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/ol-layerswitcher-master/dist/ol-layerswitcher.css" />

    <script src="libs/ol-geocoder/ol-geocoder.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/ol-geocoder/ol-geocoder.css" />

    <script src="libs/ol-popup/ol-popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/ol-popup/ol-popup.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="libs/jquery-ui-1.12.1/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>

<body>

    <div id="map" class="map">
        
        <!-- START popup -->
        <div id="popup" class="ol-popup"> 
            <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popoup-closer"></a>
            <div id="popup-content"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- END popup -->

        <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>


// JavaScript
// START of popup
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
    element: container,
    // offset: [0, -10],
    autoPan: {
        autoPanAnimation: {
            duration: 250,
        },
    },
});

closer.onclick = function () {
  overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  closer.blur();
  return false;
};

map.on('singleclick', function(evt){
    var f = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(f){
        return f
    })
    const coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    if (f){
        var n  = f.getProperties().name
        console.log(n)
        console.log(coordinate)
        
        content.innerHTML = '<h7>Station Name: <strong>' + n + '</strong></h7>';
        
        overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
    }
    else{
        overlay.setPosition(undefined);
    }
});


map.addOverlay(overlay);


    /* START popup style: */
.ol-popup{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    bottom: 12px;
    left: -50px;
    min-width: 230px;
}
.ol-popup:after, .ol-popup:before {
    top: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.ol-popup:after {
    border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-width: 10px;
    left: 48px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
.ol-popup:before {
    border-top-color: #cccccc;
    border-width: 11px;
    left: 48px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}
.ol-popup-closer {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 8px;
}
.ol-popup-closer:after{
    content: "✖";
 }
/* END popup style: */
```

Comment: Do you really have popup style definition in the middle of JS code like in the code above?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your issue.